# Downloaded zip file using w3m on linux missing

Tags: 14.04, downloads, browser, w3m

I am working on a remote Ubuntu system. I want to download a zip file from the website mentioned below to the remote system. So, I used w3m to do so as I am accessing the remote system via command line. I ran the command:
`w3m http://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/` which takes me to the website and I select the zip file "glove.6B.zip" which starts downloading the moment I click it and I can see the download process progressing.

The download process finishes successfully and then the downloaded zip and the files contained in it is displayed:

```
Archive:  /home/ubuntu/.w3m/w3mtmp2061-0.zip

  Length      Date     Time    Name
 ---------  ---------- -----   ----
171350079   2014-08-04 20:15   glove.6B.50d.txt
347116733   2014-08-04 20:14   glove.6B.100d.txt
693432828   2014-08-04 20:14   glove.6B.200d.txt
1037962819  2014-08-27 19:19   glove.6B.300d.txt
---------                     -------
2249862459                     4 files
```

The display above shows the location of the zip file in my remote system. But, when I quit w3m and go to the path `/home/ubuntu/.w3m`, the file `w3mtmp2061-0.zip` is not present there. I read somewhere that w3m saves temporary files which are deleted the moment you close w3m. How do I get the downloaded zip from the the above mentioned website to my remote system via command line. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Once you've opened the link and w3m is letting you browse the contents, you can use <kbd>Esc</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd> to save the current "document" (in this case, the zip file).

If you know ahead of time that you'll want to save the endpoint of a link, you can use either <kbd>a</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd>-<kbd>RET</kbd> to save the link.

(Source: [The w3m manual](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/MANUAL#Key:orig))

Comment: How to automate this? I want to write a script to download a file without my intervention.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest just using `wget` to download the `.zip` file as follows:

```
wget http://nlp.stanford.edu/data/glove.6B.zip
```

Comment: w3m is more convenient if the download requires a cookie. For example, a direct link to a huge zip file stored in Google Drive will first give you an HTML page for confirmation. To really download the zip file, it seems both you need a unique code from the hyperlink on the confirmation page as well as a cookie that was set.

Answer (score 0):

For users who want to download from pages which require cookies. Use `w3m` -

`sudo apt intstall w3m`

To download a file which requires authentication -
First authenticate in w3m by logging in, then download the file which requires cookies as -

`w3m -dump_source http://nlp.stanford.edu/data/glove.6B.zip >| glove.6B.zip`